# package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart Failed assertion

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to Flutter and Firestore and I realy need in your help to solve the error and build my project!
Same errors appears when I push on hamburger button and the cart button!

Please help me!

**The errors is**

```
Performing hot restart
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
Restarted application in 1 543ms.
W/DynamiteModule(28079): Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found.
I/DynamiteModule(28079): Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module 
providerinstaller:0
W/ProviderInstaller(28079): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. 
Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building Consumer<CartItemCounter>(dirty, dependencies: 
[_InheritedProviderScope<CartItemCounter>]):
The getter 'length' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: length

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Consumer<CartItemCounter> file:///C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/e_shop/lib/Store/storehome.dart:69:32
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:54:5)
#1      new CartItemCounter (package:e_shop/Counters/cartitemcounter.dart:6:90)
#2      MyApp.build.<anonymous closure> (package:e_shop/main.dart:34:47)
#3      _CreateInheritedProviderState.value (package:provider/src/inherited_provider.dart:646:35)
#4      _InheritedProviderScopeElement.value (package:provider/src/inherited_provider.dart:509:33)

====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
'package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart': Failed assertion: line 25 pos 14: 'url != 
null': is not true.
====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following assertion was thrown building MyDrawer(dirty):
'package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart': Failed assertion: line 25 pos 14: 'url != 
null': is not true.

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  MyDrawer file:///C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/e_shop/lib/Store/storehome.dart:86:17
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2      new NetworkImage (package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart:25:14)
#3      MyDrawer.build (package:e_shop/Widgets/myDrawer.dart:37:40)
#4      StatelessElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4758:28)
#5      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4684:15)
#6      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4378:5)

====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building Consumer2<TotalAmount, CartItemCounter>(dirty, 
dependencies: [_InheritedProviderScope<TotalAmount>, _InheritedProviderScope<CartItemCounter>]):
The getter 'count' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: count

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Consumer2<TotalAmount, CartItemCounter> 
file:///C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/e_shop/lib/Store/cart.dart:60:20
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:54:5)
#1      _CartPageState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:e_shop/Store/cart.dart:65:39)
#2      Consumer2.buildWithChild (package:provider/src/consumer.dart:201:19)
#3      SingleChildStatelessWidget.build (package:nested/nested.dart:260:41)
#4      StatelessElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4758:28)

====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The getter 'length' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: length
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
 Consumer<CartItemCounter> file:///C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/e_shop/lib/Widgets/customAppBar.dart:60:30
====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building Consumer2<TotalAmount, CartItemCounter>(dirty, 
dependencies: [_InheritedProviderScope<TotalAmount>, _InheritedProviderScope<CartItemCounter>]):
The getter 'count' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: count

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Consumer2<TotalAmount, CartItemCounter> 
file:///C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/e_shop/lib/Store/cart.dart:60:20
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:54:5)
#1      _CartPageState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:e_shop/Store/cart.dart:65:39)
#2      Consumer2.buildWithChild (package:provider/src/consumer.dart:201:19)
#3      SingleChildStatelessWidget.build (package:nested/nested.dart:260:41)
#4      StatelessElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4758:28)

===================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
'package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart': Failed assertion: line 25 pos 14: 'url != 
null': is not true.
====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building Consumer2<TotalAmount, CartItemCounter>(dirty, 
dependencies: [_InheritedProviderScope<TotalAmount>, _InheritedProviderScope<CartItemCounter>]):
The getter 'count' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: count

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Consumer2<TotalAmount, CartItemCounter> 
file:///C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/e_shop/lib/Store/cart.dart:60:20
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:54:5)
#1      _CartPageState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:e_shop/Store/cart.dart:65:39)
#2      Consumer2.buildWithChild (package:provider/src/consumer.dart:201:19)
#3      SingleChildStatelessWidget.build (package:nested/nested.dart:260:41)
#4      StatelessElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4758:28)

====================================================================================================
I/BiChannelGoogleApi(28079): [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: 
com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzao@490da8f
W/DynamiteModule(28079): Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
I/FirebaseAuth(28079): [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to gms implementation
D/FirebaseAuth(28079): Notifying id token listeners about user ( Cc77MTfLEKRs8L9exzWZND8i0Rg1 ).
```

**storehome.dart**

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:e_shop/Store/cart.dart';
import 'package:e_shop/Store/product_page.dart';
import 'package:e_shop/Counters/cartitemcounter.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_staggered_grid_view/flutter_staggered_grid_view.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:e_shop/Config/config.dart';
import '../Widgets/loadingWidget.dart';
import '../Widgets/myDrawer.dart';
import '../Widgets/searchBox.dart';
import '../Models/item.dart';

double width;

class StoreHome extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _StoreHomeState createState() => _StoreHomeState();
}

class _StoreHomeState extends State<StoreHome> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          flexibleSpace: Container(
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              gradient: new LinearGradient(
                colors: [Colors.blue, Colors.purpleAccent],
                begin: const FractionalOffset (0.0, 0.0),
                end: const FractionalOffset (1.0, 0.0),
                stops: [0.0, 1.0],
                tileMode: TileMode.clamp,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          title: Text(
            "Salam Market",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50.0, color: Colors.white, fontFamily: "Signatra"),
          ),
          centerTitle: true,
          actions: [
            Stack(
              children: [
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart, color: Colors.white,),
                  onPressed: ()
                  {
                    Route route = MaterialPageRoute(builder: (c) => CartPage());
                    Navigator.pushReplacement(context, route);
                 },
                ),
                Positioned(
                  child: Stack(
                    children: [
                      Icon(
                        Icons.brightness_1,
                        size: 20.0,
                        color: Colors.green,
                      ),
                      Positioned(
                        top: 3.0,
                        bottom: 4.0,
                        left: 4.0,
                        child: Consumer<CartItemCounter>(
                          builder: (context, counter, _)
                          {
                            return Text(
                          
(EcommerceApp.sharedPreferences.getStringList(EcommerceApp.userCartList).length-1).toString(),
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 12.0, fontWeight: 
FontWeight.bold),
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
        drawer: MyDrawer(),
        body: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: [
            SliverPersistentHeader(pinned: true,delegate: SearchBoxDelegate()),
            StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              stream: 
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("items").limit(15).orderBy("publishedDate", descending: 
true).snapshots(),
              builder: (context, dataSnapshot)
              {
                return !dataSnapshot.hasData
                    ? SliverToBoxAdapter(child: Center(child: circularProgress(),),)
                    : SliverStaggeredGrid.countBuilder(
                  crossAxisCount: 1,
                  staggeredTileBuilder: (c) => StaggeredTile.fit(1),
                  itemBuilder: (context, index)
                  {
                    ItemModel model = ItemModel.fromJson(dataSnapshot.data.docs[index].data());
                    return sourceInfo(model, context);
                  },
                  itemCount: dataSnapshot.data.docs.length,
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}



Widget sourceInfo(ItemModel model, BuildContext context,
    {Color background, removeCartFunction}) {
  return InkWell(
    onTap: ()
    {
      Route route = MaterialPageRoute(builder: (c) => ProductPage(itemModel: model));
      Navigator.pushReplacement(context, route);
    },
    splashColor: Colors.pink,
    child: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
      child: Container(
        height: 190.0,
        width: width,
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Image.network(model.thumbnailUrl, width: 140.0, height: 140.0,),
            SizedBox(width: 4.0,),
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  SizedBox(),
                  Container(
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                          child: Text(model.title, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 
14.0),),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 5.0,),
                  Container(
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                          child: Text(model.shortInfo, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54, 
fontSize: 12.0),),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 20.0,),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                          color: Colors.pink,
                        ),
                        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                        width: 40.0,
                        height: 43.0,
                        child: Center(
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                "50%", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0, color: Colors.white, 
fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                              ),
                              Text(
                                "OFF", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0, color: Colors.white, 
fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(width: 10.0,),
                      Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.0),
                            child: Row(
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  r"Öňki bahasy: $ ",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 14.0,
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                    decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  (model.price + model.price).toString(),
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 15.0,
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                    decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
                            child: Row(
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  r"Täze bahasy: ",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 14.0,
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                  ),
                               ),
                                Text(
                                  "man ",
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 16.0),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  (model.price).toString(),
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 15.0,
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ), 

                  Flexible(
                    child: Container(),
                  ),

                  //to implement the cart item add/remove feature
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                    child: removeCartFunction == null
                    ? IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.add_shopping_cart, color: Colors.pinkAccent,),
                      onPressed: ()
                      {
                        checkItemInCart(model.shortInfo, context);
                      },
                  )
                  : IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.delete, color: Colors.pinkAccent,),
                      onPressed: ()
                      {
                        removeCartFunction();
                        Route route = MaterialPageRoute(builder: (c) => StoreHome());
                        Navigator.pushReplacement(context, route);
                      },
                    ),
                  ),

                  Divider(
                    height: 5.0,
                    color: Colors.pink,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}



Widget card({Color primaryColor = Colors.redAccent, String imgPath}) {
  return Container(
    height: 150.0,
    width: width * .34,
    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 10),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: primaryColor,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
      boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
        BoxShadow(offset: Offset(0, 5), blurRadius: 10.0, color: Colors.grey[200]),
      ]
    ),
    child: ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
      child: Image.network(
        imgPath,
        height: 150.0,
        width: width * .34,
        fit: BoxFit.fill,
      ),
    ),
  );
}



void checkItemInCart(String shortInfoAsID, BuildContext context)
{
  EcommerceApp.sharedPreferences.getStringList(EcommerceApp.userCartList).contains(shortInfoAsID)
      ? Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Haryt arabada")
      : addItemToCart(shortInfoAsID, context);
}

addItemToCart(String shortInfoAsID, BuildContext context)
{
  List tempCartList = EcommerceApp.sharedPreferences.getStringList(EcommerceApp.userCartList);
  tempCartList.add(shortInfoAsID);

  EcommerceApp.firestore.collection(EcommerceApp.collectionUser)
  .doc(EcommerceApp.sharedPreferences.getString(EcommerceApp.userUID))
  .update({
    EcommerceApp.userCartList: tempCartList,
  }).then((v){
    Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Haryt araba goşuldy");

    EcommerceApp.sharedPreferences.setStringList(EcommerceApp.userCartList, tempCartList);

    Provider.of<CartItemCounter>(context, listen: false).displayResult();
  });
}
```

**myDrawer.dart**

```
import 'package:e_shop/Authentication/authenication.dart';
import 'package:e_shop/Config/config.dart';
import 'package:e_shop/Address/addAddress.dart';
import 'package:e_shop/Store/Search.dart';
import 'package:e_shop/Store/cart.dart';
import 'package:e_shop/Orders/myOrders.dart';
import 'package:e_shop/Store/storehome.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class MyDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        children: [
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 25.0, bottom: 10.0),
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              gradient: new LinearGradient(
                colors: [Colors.blue, Colors.purpleAccent],
                begin: const FractionalOffset (0.0, 0.0),
                end: const FractionalOffset (1.0, 0.0),
                stops: [0.0, 1.0],
                tileMode: TileMode.clamp,
              ),
            ),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Material(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(80.0)),
                  elevation: 8.0,
                  child: Container(
                    height: 160.0,
                    width: 160.0,
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                        EcommerceApp.sharedPreferences.getString(EcommerceApp.userAvatarUrl),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 10.0,),
                Text(
                  EcommerceApp.sharedPreferences.getString(EcommerceApp.userName),
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 35.0, fontFamily: "Signatra"),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 12.0,),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 1.0),
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              gradient: new LinearGradient(
                colors: [Colors.blue, Colors.purpleAccent],
                begin: const FractionalOffset (0.0, 0.0),
                end: const FractionalOffset (1.0, 0.0),
                stops: [0.0, 1.0],
                tileMode: TileMode.clamp,
              ),
            ),
            child: Column(
              children: [

                ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.home, color: Colors.white,),
                  title: Text("Esasy", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                  onTap: (){
                    Route route = MaterialPageRoute(builder: (c) => StoreHome());
                    Navigator.pushReplacement(context, route);
                  },
                ),
                Divider(height: 10.0, color: Colors.white, thickness: 6.0,),

                ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.reorder, color: Colors.white,),
                  title: Text("Zakazlarym", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                  onTap: (){
                    Route route = MaterialPageRoute(builder: (c) => MyOrders());
                    Navigator.pushReplacement(context, route);
                  },
                ),
                Divider(height: 10.0, color: Colors.white, thickness: 6.0,),

                ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart, color: Colors.white,),
                  title: Text("Arabam", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                  onTap: (){
                    Route route = MaterialPageRoute(builder: (c) => CartPage());
                    Navigator.pushReplacement(context, route);
                  },
                ),
                Divider(height: 10.0, color: Colors.white, thickness: 6.0,),

                ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.white,),
                  title: Text("Gözlemek", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                  onTap: (){
                    Route route = MaterialPageRoute(builder: (c) => SearchProduct());
                    Navigator.pushReplacement(context, route);
                  },
                ),
                Divider(height: 10.0, color: Colors.white, thickness: 6.0,),

                ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.add_location, color: Colors.white,),
                  title: Text("Täze salgy goşmak", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                  onTap: (){
                    Route route = MaterialPageRoute(builder: (c) => AddAddress());
                    Navigator.pushReplacement(context, route);
                  },
                ),
                Divider(height: 10.0, color: Colors.white, thickness: 6.0,),

                ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app, color: Colors.white,),
                  title: Text("Çykmak", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                  onTap: (){
                    EcommerceApp.auth.signOut().then((c){
                      Route route = MaterialPageRoute(builder: (c) => AuthenticScreen());
                      Navigator.pushReplacement(context, route);
                    });
                  },
                ),
                Divider(height: 10.0, color: Colors.white, thickness: 6.0,),


              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**cartitemcounter.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:e_shop/Config/config.dart';

class CartItemCounter extends ChangeNotifier
{
  int _counter = EcommerceApp.sharedPreferences.getStringList(EcommerceApp.userCartList).length-1;
  int get count => _counter;

  Future<void> displayResult() async
  {
    _counter = EcommerceApp.sharedPreferences.getStringList(EcommerceApp.userCartList).length-1;

    await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 100), (){
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }
}
```

[screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VS1Z6.jpg)

**If these codes are not enough to identify the errors, I can show the main.dart page!**

**config.dart PAGE**

```
class EcommerceApp
{
   static const String appName = 'e-Shop';

   static SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
   static User user;
   static FirebaseAuth auth;
   static FirebaseFirestore firestore ;

   static String collectionUser = "users";
   static String collectionOrders = "orders";
   static String userCartList = 'userCart';
   static String subCollectionAddress = 'userAddress';

   static final String userName = 'name';
   static final String userEmail = 'email';
   static final String userPhotoUrl = 'photoUrl';
   static final String userUID = 'uid';
   static final String userAvatarUrl = 'url';

   static final String addressID = 'addressID';
   static final String totalAmount = 'totalAmount';
   static final String productID = 'productIDs';
   static final String paymentDetails ='paymentDetails';
   static final String orderTime ='orderTime';
   static final String isSuccess ='isSuccess';

}
```

Comment: Hi Simba. How are you getting the value to EcommerceApp.userCartList and can you upload the code for this method EcommerceApp.sharedPreferences.getStringList().

Comment: Hi Victor, I have updated the code. Please take a look!

Comment: Hi Simba. From the code, it looks like you're getting the error because you've not stored any items in your shared preferences so it's returning null.

Comment: Can you run me through the scenario that causes the error to show up?

Comment: What if  i  commit it on Git to show you the project!

Comment: That works fine!

Comment: Here is the full code on the repository https://github.com/hojamedov/e_shop

Comment: I can't access it. Looks like it's private.

Comment: try this one  https://github.com/hojamedov/e_shop.git

Comment: I'm getting the same error. Page not found.

Comment: Hi Victor! Sorry for not answering for a long time! Try to follow the link again! https://github.com/hojamedov/e_shop.git

Comment: Great! Will go through it shortly.

Comment: Hi Simba, on it right now. I'm about to register and see if I can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Looks like I can't register. Can you provide test login details?

Answer (score 0):

Struggled with the same issue throughout today
Here's a solution:
Instead of
                    `(EcommerceApp.sharedPreferences.getStringList(EcommerceApp.userCartList).length-1).toString(),`
in your Storehome.dart file, use this instead

counter?.count?.toString(),